# .NET database migration toolkit

Tags: .net, database-migration

My current pet project is a language-independent database migration library ([Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby) on Google Code). It's pretty much inspired by ActiveRecord Migrations, but has a few niceties. For instance, does some basic "type inference" so you don't have to specify the type of a FK column. It's also smart enough to generate "downgrade" scripts given only "upgrade" sequence. Although migrations are written in a special DSL, this tool is primarily aimed at .NET projects. It's also database-platform-independent.

Here's a quick glimpse of the syntax:

```
  migration "Blog" revision => 1:
    type-aliases:
      type-alias N type => String, length => 200, nullable => false, default => ""

    defaults:
      default-primary-key ID type => Int32, nullable => false, identity => true

    version 1:
      add table Author:
        FirstName type => N
        LastName type => N
        EmailAddress type => N, unique => true
        Login type => N, unique => true
        Password type => Binary, length => 64, nullable => true

      add table Tag:
        Name type => N

      add table Blog:
        Name type => N
        Description type => String, nullable => false

      add table BlogPost:
        Title type => N
        Slug type => N
        BlogID references => Blog
        AuthorID references => Author

      add table BlogPostTagJunction primary-key => false:
        BlogPostID references => BlogPost
        TagID references => Tag

    version 2:
      add table BlogPostComment:
        BlogPostID references => BlogPost
        AuthorEmailAddress type => N
        Content type => String, nullable => false

    version 3:
      add table Media:
        TypeID type => Int32
        Name type => N
        MimeType type => N
        Length type => Int32
        BlogPostID nullable => true, references => BlogPost
        BlogPostCommentID nullable => true, references => BlogPostComment

      add table User:
        Login type => String, length => 200, nullable => false
        Password type => Binary, length => 64, nullable => false

        index IX_Login columns => [ID, [Login, desc]], unique => true

    version 4:
        add table Forum:
          Name type => String, length => 200, nullable => false
        add column ModeratorUserID nullable => false, references => User

    version 5:
        remove index IX_Login table => User

    version 6:
        add index IX_Login table => User, columns => [ID, [Login, desc]], unique => true

    version 7:
        BlogAuthorJunction primary-key => false:
            BlogID references => Blog
            AuthorID references => Author

        execute native-sql upgrade-resource => InsertSeedData, downgrade-resource => DeleteSeedData
```

I'm aware of other migration libraries out there, but hey, it's a pet project!

The question is: what features do you expect from database migration toolkits in general and what can you say about this particular puppy syntax-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it I have to say that it is farily easy to follow and overall the structure looks pretty clean.

The biggest features that I'm looking for in something like this are as follows.

1. Ability to make changes in a transaction to roll back should there be an issue.  (Data integrity or otherwise)
2. Ability to see the actual generated SQL scripts should the need arise
3. Automatic rollback, if a failure occurs to the last version

I have other requirements regarding the moving of keys, indexes, and the such, but it looks like you have that already handled.  For me it is really focused on the controls around the actual execution, and a quick, solid backout plan!

Answer (score 6):

I like this syntax. In your sample you focused on changing structure. But what about data manipulation?

It's very often when in migration I have to modify data (for example add some dictionary data).

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to see the ability to verify that each revision has been applied to a database. So say for example version 3 added the table 'Media'. Since then versions 4 & 5 have been added to the database but somewhere along the line 'Johnny Q Expert' deleted the table 'Media'. Now comes version 6 which needs to alter the 'Media' table (which no longer exists) - a verify function could be useful which ensures a culmination of all changes made in versions 1 thru 5 are present in the database so the next version can be applied correctly.